# How do I run Volley tests?

Tags: android, android-volley

I cloned latest version of volley from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley

I imported it in Eclipse, and tried to run the test project, but I get ClassNotFoundException

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.volley.mock.WaitableQueue$MagicStopRequest
at com.android.volley.mock.WaitableQueue.<init>(WaitableQueue.java:31)
at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcherTest.setUp(CacheDispatcherTest.java:45)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1619)
```

How do I run theses tests?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Volley framework repo comes with support for both Ant and Gradle based build systems.  Running the tests using the Gradle build system is quite simple.  I did briefly try using the Ant approach, but it wasn't as straight forward and I prefer Gradle anyhow.

First thing you'll need is to install [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/downloads) 1.10, which is the version required by Volley as of writing this answer.  Alternatively, you could clone [this mirror repo](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley), which includes some extras, such as gradlew support (Gradle bootstrapping utility for downloading and using the proper version of Gradle).

Then simply execute the following command from the project root (using either gradle or gradlew based on which option you chose above):

```
$> gradle clean connectedCheck
```

This will run the full gambit of tasks, including the tests.  It should produce an HTML test report at **build/reports/instrumentedTests/connected/index.html**, relative to the project root.

Comment: Note: as of plugin version 0.12.+, reports are moved to: /build/outputs/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html

Comment: With the command you specified, I do get reports generated; but they are empty, no tests were run in fact. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17278867) to get start with.

I write this Test Project , and import com.android.volley and com.android.volley.toolbox from the volley library. And it works ^_^

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected static final String TAG = "com.gyh.myvolleytest";

private static Response.ErrorListener createErrorListener() {
    return new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error Response code: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    };
}
private static Response.Listener<String> createSuccessListener() {
    return new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            // TODO parse response
            String string = response.toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "string :"+string);
        }
    };
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

    //it is the only button in the layout ,click to log the result
public void click(View view) {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    String url="http://192.168.1.108:8080/httptest/servlet/mainservlet?name=stack&age=23";

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            createSuccessListener(),
            createErrorListener());
    queue.add(request);
    queue.start();
}
```

}

let me know what happens ^_^